# How to disable selinux while spinning up a redhat vm in alicloud using cloud init

Tags: alibaba-cloud, alibaba-cloud-ecs

How to disable selinux while spinning up a redhat vm in alicloud using cloud init.
I have tried with below code but it doesn't work

sudo sed -i 's/enforcing/disabled/g' /etc/selinux/config /etc/selinux/config
sudo sestatus

any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to disable SELinux while spinning up a VM is by using the following command:

```
sed -i 's/enforcing/disabled/g' /etc/selinux/config /etc/selinux/config
```

or

`vi /etc/sysconfig/selinux, set selinux=disabled`

or

```
set enforce 0 sestatus
```

Please try the 3rd command, It usually works well than other two, Sometimes VM restart may be required.

Answer (score 0):

You can use write_file in cloud init like in the documentation [here](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/0.7.8/topics/examples.html#writing-out-arbitrary-files)

before encode in Base 64 is recommended.

You want to have this on your /etc/sysconfig/selinux

```
SELINUX=disabled
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

Use this cloud-init:

```
#cloud-config
# vim: syntax=yaml
#
# This is the configuration syntax that the write_files module
# will know how to understand. encoding can be given b64 or gzip or (gz+b64).
# The content will be decoded accordingly and then written to the path that is
# provided. 
#
# Note: Content strings here are truncated for example purposes.
write_files:
-   encoding: b64
    content: CiMgVGhpcyBmaWxlIGNvbnRyb2xzIHRoZSBzdGF0ZSBvZiBTRUxpbnV4...
    owner: root:root
    path: /etc/sysconfig/selinux
    permissions: '0644'
```